# How to get keys from json object

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to extract the keys from a json object using SQL on a DB2 (IBM i).

Consider the following example:

```
{ 
  "assignments": {
    "uuIdKey1": {...},
    "uuIdKey2": {...},
    "uuIdKey3": {...}
  }
}
```

I would want to somehow extract "uuIdKey1", "uuIdKey2" and "uuIdKey3".
What complicates the problem is that both the number and the name of the keys are unknown (as the json is a [open type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4)).

Is this possible using SQL on a DB2?

Comment: What Db2 platform and version? Are you using the Db2 JSON support with JSON_QUERY?

Comment: The DB2 is running on a IBM i (AS400). I'm unfortunately not sure what version of DB2 it is but it does support JSON_QUERY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find a solution to get the keys from a json using just SQL on a DB2, I was able to solve the problem by using the [YAJL library for RPG](https://www.scottklement.com/yajl/).

The library's `YAJL_OBJECT_LOOP( docNode: i: key: val )` function allows you to loop through all json props and retrieve the json keys one by one.